# What Exactly Gets Stored in MongoDB Logs?

Tags: mongodb, logging

So what gets stored in MongoDB logs?  I checked out MongoDB documentation and wasn't able to find anything concrete on the subject, so I figured I would ask here.

I had to peek into the logs to attempt to find out something, and it appears as though longer queries are in the logs.  I have profiling enabled; I'm guessing those stored queries are being echo'ed into the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All operations that take longer than 100ms are logged whether or not profiling is enabled.  Profiling setting only controls whether they are also written to a special system.profile collection.

There isn't documentation for everything that gets logged (different log levels will affect it) - if you are interested enough you can browse [the source code for MongoDB on github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo) - search for strings LOG([0-5]) or log() - this will give you an idea.

Comment: It's disappointing there isn't any real documentation on this.  You would think there would be concise settings for what gets recorded.  Thanks for the help, I'll read up on the source this weekend.